# remove elevation in dark mode (flutter)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, darkmode, elevation

I'm developing a flutter application that I need to add theme in, a already handled some problems but I have problem with elevation because in the light mode the containers in body have elevation like this (light mode):

app screen1 (light mode)

[image]

but when switching to the dark mode its's like this and the elevation is not looking nice

what I need is this (without elevation):
app screen2 (dark mode)

[image]

but what I get is this:
app screen3 (dark mode)

[image]

Comment: can you include sample code-snippet , that will reproduce the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Card you can check the theme mode and do.

```dart
Card(
  elevation:
      Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark ? 0 : 1,
),
```

or on material app.

```dart
return MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  home: TABProv(),
  darkTheme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
    cardTheme: Theme.of(context).cardTheme.copyWith(elevation: 0),
  ),
);
```

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more about [themes](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/themes)

Answer (score 0):

changing container color if dark mode enable is a easy solution, you could also customize themeData.

---

**my suggestion** is to use Color variable which changes dynamically whenever you change the theme!

CREATE NEW THEME : https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/themes

Comment: also nice solution i will give it a try ❤️